# How to get rid of daily urine odor?

Tags: dogs

I live in an apartment and I take my dog out once a day to do his business. The rest of the other times he has to go, he goes in our bathroom on a grass plastic mat. Lately my apartment has started to smell really bad because of the urine. I try to clean out the plastic with warm water and spray it with and odor free spray but the smell somehow is still there. Any advice or products that might help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I support @ana's answer... vinegar works for us. Soak whatever has urine on it in strong vinegar solution and dry if you can in direct sunlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any pet store should have multiple brands of enzyme-based pet odor cancelling liquids. These chemically combine with volatile organics, stopping them from vaporizing in the first place and thus actually stopping the odor rather than masking it.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the grass mat at some point. Vinegar and baking soda are good to remove odors

http://m.wikihow.com/Neutralize-Pet-Smell